# ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE random times in AJAX calls

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am developing a small CMS/Social network for one school, is very complex and works almost entirely with AJAX.
My problem is that randomly calls are blocked and browser error net :: ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE appears (Chrome, Firefox, IE, ...).
The URLs are OK, and if I repeat the action that ended in Error now works perfectly...

This happens in random times and have not the idea what could be the problem or where I can start looking.

The code I use is simple as this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'http://...',
    cache: false,
    data: array(),
    dataType: 'html',
    async: true,
    success: function(h){ /* ... */ }
});
```

this happens in urls with database queries and urls of basic html responses.

Chrome: "Failed to load resource net :: ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE"

Chrome: "POST > [URL] net :: ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE"

Firefox: "NetworkError 404 not found"

any help?

Comment: They seem self-explanatory -- the server is sending a blank response or reporting a 404 error. Check for errors on the server.

Comment: Thanks Barmar!
If the ajax call returns a blank response and two seconds later retry the call and everything works perfectly, the problem is not in my code, right?

Comment: I'm also getting the same error, I debug the server and found no error. I can't find the error in client side. @armate1hernan did u find the solution ?

Comment: unfortunately I could not fix yet, the only temporary solution I could think: automatically repeat the ajax call if the system encounters this error... if you know anything I'd appreciate you to tell me

Answer (score 0):

I came across this bug before when working with Framework7 xhr api. It was caused by the callback. After analyzing the bug, the console displayed a "parse error". I believe that the internal success function callback is expecting an object, but receives "undefined" and the parser throws an exception.

If possible, try to send an empty object to check whether the error vanishes.